# Thunderbird keeps freezing

Tags: windows-7, email, windows-8.1, thunderbird, freeze

Every time I do something in Thunderbird it freezes and says "Not Responding" from anywhere between 10 seconds to a full minute. When I say something I mean: moving a message, opening a message, sending a message, deleting a message, starting a new message, marking a message as junk, right clicking on a message, right clicking on a folder, opening a folder, collapsing a folder, and occasionally opening the menu, poking at the options and account settings, and paging in a long message. The only thing that doesn't take 10 second to a minute is downloading a new message, which takes at times up to 3 minutes.

I have updated to the newest version (24.5.0), deleted the .msf files, repaired all the folders, disabled all add-ons, used safe mode, disabled global search, uninstalled and reinstalled. I've also disabled virus scanning for email in McAfee.

Just to make things more interesting every now and then it works fine for a couple of minutes before freezing again. And it doesn't seem to effect any other programs when it freezes. I can use Firefox just fine as I look for answers to this problem and Thunderbird is frozen.

Does anyone have any ideas what else there is to try before I have to start using Outlook, which I never even set up on my computer.

I have a Windows 7 operating system.

**Edit:** This also happens in Windows 8.1

Comment: I have similar issues with a year's versions prior to 24.6.0 and up to 31.0 now on Win 8.1 but it happens even when the window doesn't have focus--my cursor turns to a blue circle wait cursor when hovering over it.

Comment: You might want to see [bug 1083233](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1083233) in bugzilla. I have been having this problem and have documented various attempts to corner when it happens, but it isn't just when adding attachments, even though that seems to trigger it more frequently. Like you mentioned here, it happens kind of randomly doing different things. I can just be typing in a message and it kicks off a hang for 30 seconds. Can it be auto-saving an unsent message and we just thing it's mostly random? Got me.